# Where are the error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

When i click in the button, it dont work, and I am going to "logado.html" and I dont receive the alert.
I need help, why do I receive this message?
I need that when I click in the button "Login" the js verify if "Login" or "Loginsenha" is null.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Login uCar</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="loginbox">
            <img src="img/RA.png" class="avatar">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="espaçobugado"></div>
            <form>
                <p>RA</p>
                <div class="espaçobugado2"></div>
                <input type="number" name="username" value="" id="login">
                <p>Senha</p>
                <div class="espaçobugado2"></div>    
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" id="loginsenha">
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" onclick="myLogin()"><br>
                <a href="">Perdeu sua senha?</a><br>
                <div class="espaçobugado"></div>
                <a href="">Não tem uma conta?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
var y = document.getElementById("loginsenha").value;

function myLogin() {

    if (x = "") {
        alert("Coloque seu RA por favor.")
    }
    else if (y = "") {
            alert("Coloque sua senha por favor.")
        }
        else {
            window.open("logado.html")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your function.

Keep your x, y declarations inside function, else it will always have only empty values as its declared when the script runs. Wee need the current values at each button click. So we need to keep the declaration in the function. Changed if/else statement.

`x=""` is an assignment statement does not return false ever.

Instead use `x === ""` or as i suggested in the answer

```
function myLogin() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("loginsenha").value;

  if (!x.trim()) {
    alert("Coloque seu RA por favor.")
  } else if (!y.trim()) {
    alert("Coloque sua senha por favor.")
  } else {
    window.open("logado.html")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Login uCar</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="img/RA.png" class="avatar">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="espaçobugado"></div>
    <form>
      <p>RA</p>
      <div class="espaçobugado2"></div>
      <input type="number" name="username" value="" id="login">
      <p>Senha</p>
      <div class="espaçobugado2"></div>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" id="loginsenha">
      <input type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick="myLogin()"><br>
      <a href="">Perdeu sua senha?</a><br>
      <div class="espaçobugado"></div>
      <a href="">Não tem uma conta?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>


  <script>
    function myLogin() {
      var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("loginsenha").value;

      if (!x.trim()) {
        alert("Coloque seu RA por favor.")
      } else if (!y.trim()) {
        alert("Coloque sua senha por favor.")
      } else {
        window.open("logado.html")
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) use `==` no `=`

2) get `x` value and `y` value `inside` the function no `out` the function.

```
function myLogin() {

  var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("loginsenha").value;

  if (x == "") {
    alert("Coloque seu RA por favor.");
  }

  else if (y == "") {
    alert("Coloque sua senha por favor.");
  }

  else {
    window.open("logado.html")
  }

}
```

```js
function myLogin() {
      var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("loginsenha").value;

  if (x == "") {
    alert("Coloque seu RA por favor.");
  }

  else if (y == "") {
    alert("Coloque sua senha por favor.");
  }

  else {
    window.open("logado.html")
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="img/RA.png" class="avatar">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="espaçobugado"></div>
  <form>
    <p>RA</p>
    <div class="espaçobugado2"></div>
    <input type="number" name="username" value="" id="login">
    <p>Senha</p>
    <div class="espaçobugado2"></div>    
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" id="loginsenha">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" onclick="myLogin()"><br>
    <a href="">Perdeu sua senha?</a><br>
    <div class="espaçobugado"></div>
    <a href="">Não tem uma conta?</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is using assignment, not conditional logic. For example,

```
x = ""
```

should say

```
x === ""
```

Your current logic is being evaluated as follows:

```
if (x = "") ~> if ("") ~> if (false)
```

So your conditions are never true, and else is always called.